# Convert a string with dot and comma to numeric

Tags: r, type-conversion, numeric

Is there a way to convert into a numeric type a string type? 
For instance:

```
> as.numeric("1.560,65")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I receive the above error.
I need the thousands to be displayed and separated by dot while (i.e. 1.560) the decimals to be displays and separated by comma.

```
> as.numeric("1.560")
[1] 1.56
> as.numeric("1.560")>2
[1] FALSE
```

In the above example while I want R to convert 1.560 into numeric it translates it to 1.56 which is not in thousands and this lower than 2 and thus my computations are wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just so i understand you right: do you want to read comma and dot as decimal, and only if both are present read the comma as decimal and ignore the dot?

Comment: @snaut I want to tell R to print the results in numerical format with dot as separator of thousands so I can generate reports.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a regexpr to format your strings into an understandable format for R and then convert it as numeric

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", gsub("\\.","", "1.560,65")))
[1] 1560.65
```

For numeric formating see `formatC`

```
formatC(1560.65, format = "f", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
[1] "1.560,6500"
```

Comment: Is there any way to tell R to present numbers as in this format: 1.560 which is 1 thousand 560. I have created a master data.frame which I use to generate tables and graphs and my organization requires dot "." to be set as thousand separators.

Comment: No you can format them, but they will be strings and not numerics anymore

Comment: I know and my organization requires the reports to have the thousands separator marked. When I try to convert to string and then back to numeric, R understands it wrong and thus the computations are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

String pattern matching and replacement can be done by using `gsub` function. Here is an example for your case:

```
str_numbers <- c("1.560,65", "134,2","123","0,32")
as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", gsub("\\.", "", str_numbers)))
```

The first call replaces the `.` with empty string. The second the `,` with `.`

```
> (tmp <- gsub("\\.", "", str_numbers))
[1] "1560,65" "134,2"   "123"     "0,32"   
> gsub(",", "\\.", tmp)
[1] "1560.65" "134.2"   "123"     "0.32"
```